# Menu Management with Authorization

Tags: java, menu, authorization, spark-java

I have an user which has certain limitations on menu items those can be access by user. I am able to restrict user on Ui from performing not authorized actions. I have a problem to limit user on the server side to protect from making it accessible through  various rest clients.

EX: item A has only GET api permission and B also has only GET permissions. I am trying to perform POST for A so my concern is how do I ensure that call is for A or item B.

I am using java8 and spark java framework. Please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.

NOTE: Adding authorization for each route separately will not be a good idea so please help to write a common generalize method.

Comment: You can get all details of the request in interceptors like if the request is get/post, resource class information, method name that is going to be invoked . This interceptors will be called every time your rest method is about to be invoked. This might be helpful ,but I am not quite sure if you were looking for this.

Comment: thanks @Jimmy but I am more interested if it can be handled routes layer or through some auth config.